# Groupby and Sum from a datatable or dataview

Tags: vb.net, datatable, grouping, dataview

I have a datatable (filled from xls file) with different sort of fruits and legumes.

I make a dataview from this datatable, and using RowFilter to only have the potatoes and tomatoes.

Now, I try to make a groupby (with column 'Name') and making a sum from another column 'Quantity'.

Actually :

```
Name    |  Quantity  | color
tomatoe |     2      |  red
tomatoe |     1      |  red
potatoe |     5      |  yellow
tomatoe |     1      |  red
potatoe |     1      |  yellow
```

I would return a datatable or dataview like this :

```
Name    |  Quantity | color
tomatoe |     4     |  red
potatoe |     6     |  yellow
```

how can I do that ?

Sorry if this is simple, but I'm noob with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `LINQ`, in this case `Linq-To-DataTable`:

```
Dim fruitGroups = table.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(row) row.Field(Of String)("Name"))
```

Now you can create the result table:

```
Dim tableResult = table.Clone() ' empty table with same columns
For Each grp In fruitGroups 
    tableResult.Rows.Add(grp.Key, grp.Sum(Function(row) row.Field(Of Int32)("Quantity")), grp.First().Field(Of String)("Color"))
Next
```

That will take an arbitrary color of each group(the first). So if you want to group by the combination of `Name` and `Color` you have to group by an anonymous type containg both:

```
Dim fruitGroups = table.AsEnumerable().
    GroupBy(Function(row) New With {
        Key .Name = row.Field(Of String)("Name"),
        Key .Color = row.Field(Of String)("Color")
    })

Dim tableResult = table.Clone()
For Each grp In fruitGroups
    tableResult.Rows.Add(grp.Key.Name, grp.Sum(Function(row) row.Field(Of Int32)("Quantity")), grp.Key.Color)
Next
```

If you need a `DataView` you can use `tableResult.DefaultView`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this quick response and your explanations. This is clear and I used it with success.

Answer (score 0):

I have a follow-up question about this solution. If you have to declare grp what would the type be. I am using a system that allows you to use VB.NET to create workflow scripts I have adopted this code but the system requires all variables type to be defined before they can be used.

Please note Option Strict OFF and system still requires you to declare variable

Comment: When I use grp.GetType() ,  {Name = "Grouping" FullName = "System.Linq.Lookup`2+Grouping[[VB$AnonymousType_0`16[[System.Object, mscorlib,

Comment: Rather comment on the solution than add an answer to the question for a follow up question